# Expo Deploy - uses-sdk:minSdkVersion value (24) specified in the manifest file is ignored. It is overridden

Tags: android, react-native, expo, build.gradle, android-manifest

Please can someone solve this for me, been on this for days. This is for a react native app being built in expo cloud.

In short I am trying to change the build.gradle minSdkVersion from 21 to 24 in expo cloud build. The long version is below.

Here is the issue I am trying to solve:

```
uses-sdk:minSdkVersion value (24) specified in the manifest file is ignored. It is overridden by the value declared in the DSL or the variant API, or 1 if not declared/present. Current value is (21).
```

The original error was:

```
uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 21 cannot be smaller than version 24 declared in library
```

After digging I found that the AndroidManifest file was setting the minSdkVersion to 21 but it needed to be 24. After many hours of trial and error I got this plugin to work:

```
const { withAndroidManifest } = require("@expo/config-plugins");

function addMinSdkVersion(androidManifest) {
  const { manifest } = androidManifest;

  if (!manifest.$) {
    console.warn("addMinSdkVersion: Missing root attributes in manifest?");
    return androidManifest;
  }

  manifest.$["xmlns:android"] = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";
  manifest["uses-sdk"] = [{
    $: {
      "android:minSdkVersion": "24",
    },
  }];

  return androidManifest;
}

module.exports = function withAndroidMainActivityAttributes(config) {
  return withAndroidManifest(config, (config) => {
    config.modResults = addMinSdkVersion(config.modResults);
    return config;
  });
};
```

Now it seems that this value from the Android Manifest is being overwritten by the build.gradle setting. I have tried many many ways to fix this and non have worked. Here's my latest plugin attempt:

```
const { withProjectBuildGradle } = require("@expo/config-plugins");

function modifyMinSdkVersion(buildGradle) {
    const { buildscript } = buildGradle;
    console.log(buildscript);
    buildscript.minSdkVersion = 24
    console.log(buildGradle);
    return buildGradle;
}

module.exports = function withMinSdkVersion(config) {
  return withProjectBuildGradle(config, (config) => {
    config.modResults.contents = modifyMinSdkVersion(config.modResults.contents);
    return config;
  });
};
```

This is executed here in the app.json file:

```
"plugins": [
    "./plugins/android-manifest.plugin.js",
    "./plugins/android-gradle.plugin.js"
]
```

I have also tried these settings in the app.json:

```
"android": {
  "minSdkVersion": 24,
}

"mods": {
  "android": {
    "manifest": {
      "usesSdk": {
        "minSdkVersion": 24
      }
    }
  }
}

"expo-build-properties":
 {
   "android": {
     "minSdkVersion": 24,

   }
 }
```

Also tried this but .replace is not recognised as a function:

```
const { withProjectBuildGradle } = require("@expo/config-plugins");

function modifyMinSdkVersion(buildGradle) {
  const modifiedBuildGradle = buildGradle.replace(/minSdkVersion\s+\d+/, 'minSdkVersion 24');
  return modifiedBuildGradle;
}

module.exports = function withMinSdkVersion(config) {
  return withProjectBuildGradle(config, (config) => {
    config.modResults.contents = modifyMinSdkVersion(config.modResults.contents);
    return config;
  });
};
```

If anyone has any information that may guide me to the solution I am all ears. Its worth noting that I could have changed the version of plugins to try and get them all compatible with sdk 21, however there were a few of them which would have taken a while to find the correct versions to use and get them working together. It would also have meant lots of testing, the app has been deploying and working fine in IOS.

Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for outlining all of this. Were you every able to get this working? I'm looking to upgrade the `minSdkVersion` from 21 to at least 23 in an Expo 49 project currently.